# Order channel categories on the navigation

Tags: categories

I am a novice with ExpressionEngine and still learning.

How can one order channel categories in an ascending or descending order ?

For example :

```
<!-- ABOUT US -->

<li><a href="/corporate">About Us</a>
    <!-- DROPDOWN NAV -->
    {exp:channel:categories channel="corporate" category_group="8" dynamic="no" style="nested" status="{published-status}" show_empty="no" id="nav_categories" class="dropdown"}
    {if category_id != "82"}
        {if category_id != "116"}
    <a href="{path='corporate/topic'}">{cap_category_name_catgrpid-8}</a>
    {/if}
    {/if}
    {if count == "{total_results}"}
        <a href="/get-involved/item/parachutes-sponsors">Our sponsors</a>
    {/if}
{/exp:channel:categories}
</li>
```

Any suggestion will be helpful

Answer (score 2):

The native `exp:channel:categories` tag doesn't offer any type of sorting parameters. I suggest using [GW Code Categories](http://gwcode.com/add-ons/gwcode-categories) as it has a ton of useful options.

```
{exp:gwcode_categories
    channel="corporate"
    group_id="8"
    excl_cat_id="82|116"
    orderby="cat_name"
    sort="asc"
    style="nested"
    status="Open"
    show_empty="no"
    id="nav_categories"
    class="dropdown"
}
    ...
{/exp:gwcode_categories}
```

You can also disregard the category conditionals as I excluded them with the `excl_cat_id` parameter.